# htaccess rewrite with date and url conditions not working

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, time

I need for a url on my existing website to point to an outside website after a certain date (3/31/17 at 7:30 p.m.). If it makes a difference, my website is coded in Wordpress, and I have no access to the outside website to know how it was created. The code I have so far is:

```
RewriteCond %{TIME} >20170331193000
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /mypermalink.*
RewriteRule (.*) https://outside.website.com/take/me/away [L,R=302,QSA]
```

If anyone can help me figure this out, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you test it as `3/31/17` is in future

Comment: I tried making it less than when testing.